# how do you manage your Oracle APEX deployments?

Tags: deployment, oracle-apex

how do you manage your deployments on APEX?

with help from a 3rd party tool? or with an in-house solution?

I am looking for something that handle versioning and package deployments from dev,test,preprod to prod and I'd like to hear your opinions.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We are using Gitlab and cx_Oracle (in Python) for versioning/deployment of db objects and SQLcl (also through Python) to import/export/version Apex Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Insum has provided an elegant and open source solution, see a short video [here](https://youtu.be/IovJpAwFxW4) and Github repo [here](https://github.com/insum-labs/starter-project-template)